# How to output highest number out of 3 numbers?

Tags: python, numbers, project, output, highest

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, I'm rather new to Python. I need to create a program for a school project. The project outline says this: Students can earn their final mark in a course in two ways. First the course work can be worth 
60%, the final project worth 20% and the final exam worth 20%. Alternately, the course work can be worth 70%, the final project worth 10% and the final exam worth 20%. Use the following code as a start and create a program that outputs the highest grade the student could achieve.

```
course = 87
finalProject = 75
exam = 82
```

Once again, I apologize if this seems like a stupid question, I'm quite new to Python. I just need to know the best way of going about doing this.

Comment: What have you done so far? You can't just ask for a solution without showing some effort.

Comment: I've attempted to begin writing the code as best I could, but it wasn't correct, so I discarded it. Sorry if I had done something wrong or asked a question incorrectly; I'm new here. I apologize.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not enough to ask a question, you have to show us what you've done thus far. People get spammed with downvotes when they post a question saying "how do I do this entire thing".

Comment: Well that's not what I'm asking. I should have been more specific. I am just asking for a starting point, not the entire code. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @user2836628: It's good practice on SO to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing but maths. Really...

```
# Your starting point
course = 87
finalProject = 75
exam = 82

# What I would "crunch" into a calculator besides the variables
total1 = (course * 0.6) + (finalProject * 0.2) + (exam * 0.2)
total2 = (course * 0.7) + (finalProject * 0.1) + (exam * 0.2)

# Printing my computed answers just to make sure I can tell if it gives the right output
print "Total1: %s\tTotal2: %s" % (total1, total2)

# Printing the highest one. 
print "\nYour mark is: %s" % max(total1, total2)
```

See it in action: http://codepad.org/UsfAVC30

You might find this interesting: [Interesting article from meta.programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1)

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `max(...)` function just returns the greatest argument passed to it; it's also usable with lists: `max([1, 2, 3])` => `3`.

In your case:

```
highest = max(
    course * 0.6 + finalProject * 0.2 + exam * 0.2,
    course * 0.7 + finalProject * 0.1 + exam * 0.2
)
```

Comment: Amazing... If you replace the first, second, fourth and fifth comma with a plus(+) then you literally did his project in one line.

Comment: @Touch: Oops, it was supposed to be `+` not `,`... corrected the mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple math problem, being new to Python is irrelevant. Calculate the final mark using both equations, then check which one is larger. Output the value of the largest one.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that it is a simple math problem, one I can solve quite easily, however, I am not sure as to what code I should write. Sorry if I am frustrating you.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the first and the second grading system right? Shouldn't it be just two variables? You can use `max()` to compare to numbers: `max(a, b)` returns the higher between two numbers. The rest you can solve yourself.